# Spring Boot MultiValueMap parameters in Postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, postman

I have implemented OAuth2 in Spring boot. It works well when testing it in JUnit but I always get unauthorized when I try the API in postman.

test function in JUnit:

```
private String obtainAccessToken(String username, String password) throws Exception {
    final MultiValueMap<String, String> params = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    params.add("grant_type", "password");
    params.add("client_id", CLIENT_ID);
    params.add("username", username);
    params.add("password", password);


    ResultActions result = mockMvc.perform(post("/oauth/token")
            .params(params)
            .with(httpBasic(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET))
            .accept(CONTENT_TYPE))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(CONTENT_TYPE));


    String resultString = result.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();

    JacksonJsonParser jsonParser = new JacksonJsonParser();
    return jsonParser.parseMap(resultString).get("access_token").toString();
}
```

I tried following APIs in postman:

POST type `http://localhost:8080/oauth/token` with content type `application/json`
in Body section I selected raw and JSON :

```
{
    "grant_type":"password",
    "client_id":"clientIdPassword",
    "username":"a",
    "password":"a"
}
```

It showed 401 Unauthorized. Then I also tried like this :

Post type with content type `application/json`, `http://localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=clientIdPassword&username=a&password=a`. This also showed 401 Unauthorized.

My question is how can I set `MultiValueMap` as parameter in Postman?

Comment: Are you setting basic authentication when you do it from Postman?

Comment: Hey @Eniss did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

you should use authorization tab of postman to send auth headers along with request body however you like.
PFA sample image[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you send the request via POSTMAN tool, select the type of HTTP method (POST, PUT, DELETE), then select the "raw" option in "Body" tab and then just add the JSON of the Map in it. Make sure you have selected "Content-type" as "application/json" in "Headers" .

Answer (score 0):

You should add those param value in form-data under body

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).